# delete records older than 24 hours in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, sql-delete

I want to delete all the records which is older than 24 hours. I am using the below query for the same but sometimes doesn't run perfectly. I want to know whether my query is right or wrong ? Or which is better way to do so.

```
delete from TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION where EVENT_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1;
```

Comment: "but sometimes doesn't run perfectly" can you expand on this?

Comment: Your query is quite right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want older than *24 hours* then do:

```
where event_date < sysdate - 1
```

If you want *before yesterday*, then do:

```
where event_date < trunc(sysdate) - 1
```

As for performance, that depends on how many rows are being deleted.  If your table only has thousands of rows, then this is fine.  If it has millions of rows, then you might want an index on `event_date`.  Or, you might even want to take a different approach -- selecting the data into a temporary table, truncating the original table, and then re-inserting it.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your reply. I think its because of trunk i was having some issues.

Comment: Nice answer. I see one more problem: trunc ist a PL/SQL Function. Oracle sometimes decide to call all function in the where clause for every row even when we as the developer want it to be called one times and the result used for all rows. Dont know how Oracle choose to handle trunc. 
And for Rahul: If you have to execute thes querry every 24h on a big ammount of data you shut take a look if Partitioning is somethink for you. It will reduce the ammout of work to a truncate. But its a feature that cost extra.

Comment: I have question with TRUNCATE. Is it possible to use TRUNCATE with the options as well ? For example can i use TRUNCATE to delete the data older than 24 hours ? Because i have thousands of rows to be deleted, sometimes the performance will be slow using delete statement.

Comment: @Rahul . . . No.  `truncate` empties a table entirely.  You could partition by the data by day and drop a partition.  You can copy the data, truncate the data, and re-insert it -- that is often faster than doing zillions of deletes or updates.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is deleting records where the `EVENT_DATE` is before yesterday.

If you want to delete records that are over 24 hours old, try:

```
delete from TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION where (SYSDATE - EVENT_DATE) > 1;
```

Comment: little bit confusion here. I want to delete records which is older than 24 hours from the SYSDATE. For example if the current time is 20.03.2015 10:33:00 then i want to keep records from 19:03:2015 10:33:00 till 20.03.2015 10:33:00 and delete the older records which is older than 19.03.2015 10:33:00. Will your query works in this case ?

Comment: Yes, and the answer from @GordonLinoff will work as well

Comment: Is it with trunct(sysdate) or with trunc() ?

Comment: for your purposes, you should not use `trunc()`. `trunc()` removes the time component of a date time i.e. `trunc('2015-03-20 09:55:21') = '2015-03-20 00:00:00'`